# Google Adsense: is it possible to force unit to display 4 ads in horizontal unit?

Tags: javascript, adsense

Google Adsense: is it possible to force unit to display 4 ads in horizontal unit?
Now i get random sizes, sometime just one add in the horizontal unit, sometimes 4... what's the rationale behind it?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you have this option. You can only control "text-only" vs "media" vs "mixed" option.

The rationale - "Google knows better". Adsense would pick ad that has the best probability for your visitor to follow, based on his recent browsing history, interests etc. Something just impossible for you to know/control.